# How can this stored procedure be more elegant using unpivot

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, pivot

The data I have is in the following format:

```
ID          Category        Gender        Cost
1              C1             M            40
2              C2             F            50
3              C3             M            60
4              C1             F            40
5              C3             M            70
6              C3             F            50
```

.
.
.
and so on

Only C1, C2 and C3 exist as categories

The result I need is:

```
Category  Male %  Female %   Avg. Cost
   C1       0.5    0.5        40
   C2       0      1          50
   C3       0.6    0.4        60
```

What I have done in the stored procedure is I declared variables for C1 count, C2 count and C3 count, C1 female count, C2 female count, C3 female count, C1 Total Cost, C2 Total Cost, C3 Total cost, you get the idea. Then I calculated the average cost and male / female percentages.

It works but it's not a very elegant solution. I couldn't get the unpivot query to work so it gives me the result I need. Can this be done using unpivot or am I misunderstanding how pivots work? I tried something like this below but couldn't figure out how to include M/F percentage and average cost per category.

Thanks.

Something like this (which is incomplete):

```
Declare @TotalCount int;
SELECT @TotalCount = count(*) from MyTable;

SELECT Category, p.Total, CAST(p.Total * 1.0 / @TotalCount AS float) AS Percentage FROM --How to get F or M percentage, Average Cost Per Category , etc?
   (
        SELECT ISNULL(SUM(c.C1), 0) AS C1,
                      ISNULL(SUM(c.C2), 0) AS C2,
                      ISNULL(SUM(c.C3), 0) AS C3
               FROM
               (SELECT CASE WHEN Category = 'C1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS C1,
                      CASE WHEN Category = 'C2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS C2,
                      CASE WHEN Category = 'C3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS C3
               FROM @Candidates
               ) c --Do I need
   ) a
   UNPIVOT
        (
               Total FOR Suitability IN (
                      C1,
                      C2,
                      C3
               )
        ) p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below query:

```
select 
    Category,
    CAST(1.00*sum(case when Gender='M' then 1 else 0 end)/COUNT(Category) AS NUMERIC(18,1)) [Male %], 
    CAST(1.00*sum(case when Gender='F' then 1 else 0 end)/COUNT(Category) AS NUMERIC(18,1)) [Female %],  
    AVG(Cost) [Avg. Cost]
from tbl 
group by Category
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4b26/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a name for this type of select for me to read further?

Comment: We used aggregate functions like SUM, AVG for this query. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173454.aspx